# XSLT: How to do a GROUP_BY?

Tags: xslt, muenchian-grouping

This is the sample XML that I am working on:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <content_id>ID_001</content_id>
    <record_id>Value_1</record_id>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <content_id>ID_001</content_id>
    <record_id>Value_2</record_id>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <content_id>ID_002</content_id>
    <record_id>Value_3</record_id>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

I would like to transform this to

```
<Results>
    <Record>
        <id>ID_001
        </id>
        <item>Value_1
        </item>
        <item>Value_2
        </item>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <id>ID_002
        </id>
        <item>Value_3
        </item>
    </Record>
</Result>
```

What's causing the trouble is that I am not able to do a `GROUP BY <content_id>` in the XSL to get the result.

Could I get any help in this?

Comment: Look up the tag [_muenchian-grouping_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/muenchian-grouping) that I added to find a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the version of XSLT, but if you can use version 2.0, then use `for-each-group`.

See e.g. http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-for-each-group (or countless examples in the web, even on stacktrace).

To get proper grouping use `group-by="Table/content_id"` attribute.

Comment: Thanks ! this if for 1.0.

Comment: I got that group-by clause. That would help, but how to have two separate elements for <record_id>. i.e. <Record>
        <id>ID_001
        </id>
        <item>Value_1
        </item>
        <item>Value_2
        </item>
    </Record> group-by would have these two values value_1 and value_2 together. I would want them as separate items being grouped under content_id